# SQL Query for fetching 2 results as single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this. I want to get employee records to get their current Designation(whose effectiveto is null) and the date where they FIRST joined as Trainee(min(effectivefrom) where Designation= Trainee)

```
+----+-------------------+---------------+-------------+
| ID | Designation       | EffectiveFrom | EffectiveTo |
+----+-------------------+---------------+-------------+
| 1  | Trainee           | 01/01/2000    | 31/12/2000  |
| 1  | Assistant Manager | 01/01/2001    | 31/12/2004  |
| 1  | Suspended         | 01/01/2005    | 01/02/2005  |
| 1  | Trainee           | 02/03/2005    | 31/03/2005  |
| 1  | Manager           | 01/04/2005    | NULL        |
| 2  | Trainee           | 01/01/2014    | 31/12/2014  |
| 2  | Developer         | 01/01/2015    | 31/12/2016  |
| 2  | Architect         | 01/01/2017    | NULL        |
+----+-------------------+---------------+-------------+
```

How to get result like this

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID | Current Designation | Date First Employed |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | Manager             | 01/01/2000          |
| 2  | Architect           | 01/01/2014          |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date of first employment could be located using `CROSS APPLY` and `SELECT TOP(1)`

```
CREATE TABLE #table1(
  ID int, 
  Designation varchar(17),
  EffectiveFrom datetime,
  EffectiveTo varchar(10));
    
INSERT INTO #table1
    (ID, Designation, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo)
VALUES
    (1, 'Trainee', '2000-01-01 01:00:00', '31/12/2000'),
    (1, 'Assistant Manager', '2001-01-01 01:00:00', '31/12/2004'),
    (1, 'Suspended', '2005-01-01 01:00:00', '01/02/2005'),
    (1, 'Trainee', '2005-02-03 01:00:00', '31/03/2005'),
    (1, 'Manager', '2005-01-04 01:00:00', NULL),
    (2, 'Trainee', '2014-01-01 01:00:00', '31/12/2014'),
    (2, 'Developer', '2015-01-01 01:00:00', '31/12/2016'),
    (2, 'Architect', '2017-01-01 01:00:00', NULL);

select t.ID, t.Designation [Current Designation], 
       ef.EffectiveFrom [Date First Employed]
from #table1 t
     cross apply (select top(1) cast(tt.EffectiveFrom as date) EffectiveFrom
                  from #table1 tt
                  where t.ID=tt.ID
                        and Designation='Trainee'
                  order by tt.EffectiveFrom) ef
where t.EffectiveTo is null;
```

```
ID  Current Designation Date First Employed
1   Manager             2000-01-01
2   Architect           2014-01-01
```

Comment: Thanks. But this query is not giving correct effective from. It should be oldest effective from

Comment: It was a typo.  The 2nd column should've been Designation.  Works now

Comment: Thanks Steve. It worked for me.But execution time increased by 23% due to this cross apply. Since i am fetching more than 100k records, this delay is quite visible.

Answer (score 0):

One method is conditional aggregation.  It is a bit unclear how you define "current", but assuming this is associated with `EffectiveTo` being `NULL`:

```
select id,
       max(case when EffectiveTo is null then designation end) as current_designation,
       min(effectivefrom) as start_ate
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Getting this error : Column 'employee.EffectiveTo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Sanjay . . . This is a simple aggregation query.  I'm not sure why I put in a window function.  It is fixed now.

Comment: Wouldn't it better to have designation='trainee' condition for min(effectivefrom) (only if there is any possibility to have min(effectivefrom) for any other designation)? min(case when designation ='trainee' then EffectiveFrom end ) as start_ate

Comment: Thanks Gordon. But i am getting multiple rows for each employee now. Sorry for being dumb, SQL is not my primary skills.

Comment: This answer looks good to me. I have created a SQL Fiddle to demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b7f7b/3/0

Comment: @Sanjay . . . The `group by id` guarantees that the result set has only one row per `id`.  Perhaps you have employees with multiple ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query:

```
select id,max(current_designation) current_designation,min(date_first_employee) date_first_employee from 
(select id,
       max(case when EffectiveTo is null then designation end) over (partition by id) as current_designation,      
       (case when Designation='Trainee' then EffectiveFrom end) Date_First_Employee
from desig) t
group by id
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks but from this query i am getting multiple rows for single record. I am looking for single row for each employee

Comment: would you please share the data of that employee for which you are getting multiple rows. So that, I can check which condition i missed.

Comment: getting multiple for all employees. lets say if my employee is having 3 rows. I am getting 3 rows

Comment: There should only be two rows for both my query and Gordon's. Please share your query which you are executing.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a rather simple self-join assuming that the `EffectiveFrom` and `EffectiveTo` columns are always filled in appropriately (i.e. there's always only one `NULL` value for `EffectiveTo` of a given `ID`). Since it's possible for someone to be a `Trainee` twice, you also need to use a [**window function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to filter out only the earliest `Traininee` `EffectiveFrom` date:

```
WITH CTE_Designations AS
(
    SELECT T1.ID, T1.Designation AS CurrentDesignation, ISNULL(T2.EffectiveFrom, T1.EffectiveFrom) AS DateFirstEmployed -- If the join fails below then that means the earliest Designation is in T1 (e.g. that is the 'Trainee' record)
    FROM DesignationsTable AS T1
    LEFT JOIN DesignationsTable AS T2
        ON T1.ID = T2.ID
        AND T1.Designation <> T2.Designation
        AND T2.Designation = 'Trainee'
    WHERE T1.EffectiveTo IS NULL
),
CTE_Designations_FirstEmployedOnly AS
(
    SELECT ID, CurrentDesignation, DateFirstEmployed, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateFirstEmployed) AS SortId -- Generates a unique ID per DateFirstEmployed row for each Designation.ID sorted by DateFirstEmployed
    FROM CTE_Designations
)

SELECT ID, CurrentDesignation, DateFirstEmployed
FROM CTE_Designations_FirstEmployedOnly
WHERE SortId = 1
```

Results per your example data:

[image: Example Results]

Results if you had an additional person who was still a `Trainee`:

[image: Example Results 2]

Comment: This doesn't work for the given data which includes a case where someone has been a trainee twice. It also won't work if a person is still a trainee.

Comment: @SteveLovell Yup just noticed the double `Trainee` rows for the same `ID` and it's fixed now. :)

Comment: @SteveLovell And it actually does work when someone is still a `Trainee`, hence the `LEFT JOIN` and `ISNULL()` check. I just ran it on my Test database for that case.

Comment: Yep, this one now gives the right results and handles my imagined extra case (the original didn't have the `left join`). The query is much more complex than some of the other answers though ...

Comment: @SteveLovell The original did have a `LEFT JOIN` if you check the answer update history. ;) But all good, thanks for pointing out the double `Trainee` case. :) Complexity is subjective, **window functions** are very useful in SQL and definitely worth knowing, and it sounds like the other answers weren't working for OP for some reason since he posted about this again on DBA.StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

This is another possilbe solution

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c70773/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`ID` int, `Designation` varchar(17), `EffectiveFrom` datetime, `EffectiveTo` varchar(10))
;
    
INSERT INTO table1
    (`ID`, `Designation`, `EffectiveFrom`, `EffectiveTo`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Trainee', '2000-01-01 01:00:00', '31/12/2000'),
    (1, 'Assistant Manager', '2001-01-01 01:00:00', '31/12/2004'),
    (1, 'Suspended', '2005-01-01 01:00:00', '01/02/2005'),
    (1, 'Trainee', '2005-02-03 01:00:00', '31/03/2005'),
    (1, 'Manager', '2005-01-04 01:00:00', NULL),
    (2, 'Trainee', '2014-01-01 01:00:00', '31/12/2014'),
    (2, 'Developer', '2015-01-01 01:00:00', '31/12/2016'),
    (2, 'Architect', '2017-01-01 01:00:00', NULL)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    (SELECT 
            `Designation`
        FROM
            table1
        WHERE
            `EffectiveFrom` =  (SELECT 
                            MAX(`EffectiveFrom`)
                        FROM
                            table1
                        WHERE
                            ID = t1.ID)) AS  `Current Designation`
 ,DATE(MIN(`EffectiveFrom`)) AS `Date First Employed`
FROM
    table1 t1
    GROUP BY ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c70773/5/0)**:

```
| ID | Current Designation | Date First Employed |
|----|---------------------|---------------------|
|  1 |             Trainee |          2000-01-01 |
|  2 |           Architect |          2014-01-01 |
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns the result shown for the given data

Solves for "current Designation(whose effectiveto is null) and the date where they FIRST joined".  Also handles terminated employees where EffectiveTo is not NULL as well as new employees with a single row.  Replace "@t" with your table name.

```
SELECT a.Id, d.Designation, a.EffectiveFrom
FROM
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY EffectiveFrom ASC ) r FROM @t) a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY EffectiveFrom DESC ) r FROM @t) d
ON a.Id = d.Id
WHERE a.r = 1 AND d.r = 1
```

Result:

```
Id  Designation EffectiveFrom
1   Manager 2000-01-01
2   Architect   2014-01-01
```